# Serving multiple mbtiles that have the same style

Tags: mbtiles, maplibre-gl

I'm generating a few `mbtiles` with TileMaker, using the exact same configuration:

- test1.mbtiles
- test2.mbtiles

Those tiles have a `source-layer=poi`.

I would like to serve them, without merging them beforehand (as I'm planning to have a mbtiles/country) with tileserver-gl, using maplibre-gl-js.

For that, I'm using a `style.json` that will eventually contains a bunch of layers, with some layers based on the POIs:

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "name": "OSM Bright",
  "layers": [
    {
        "id": "poi_z15",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "tests",
        "source-layer": "poi",
        "minzoom": 15,
        xxxxx,
     },
     {
        "id": "poi_z16",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "tests",
        "source-layer": "poi",
        "minzoom": 16,
        xxxxx,
     },
```

Those layers, are based on `"source-layer": "poi"` and should work for both mbtiles (test1 and test2). The problem is that the layer definition requests a `source`, that I've tagged `"source": "tests"` in this example.

How, in this style, do you link both mbtiles ?
If I do

```
...
"sources": {
    "tests": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "mbtiles://test1.mbtiles"
    },
...
```

It will work for the mbtiles test1. Now if I want to add the second mbtiles test2, the only way I've found so far is to create a new source, hence my style would become

```
...
"sources": {
    "test1": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "mbtiles://test1.mbtiles"
    },
    "test2": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "mbtiles://test2.mbtiles"
    },
...
```

and in that case I need to duplicate my layers as:

```
{
 ...
  "layers": [
    {
        "id": "poi_z15",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "test1",
        "source-layer": "poi",
        "minzoom": 15,
        xxxxx,
     },
     {
        "id": "poi_z16",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "test1",
        "source-layer": "poi",
        "minzoom": 16,
        xxxxx,
     },
{
        "id": "poi_z15",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "test2",
        "source-layer": "poi",
        "minzoom": 15,
        xxxxx,
     },
     {
        "id": "poi_z16",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "test2",
        "source-layer": "poi",
        "minzoom": 16,
        xxxxx,
     },
```

If I have 100 mbtiles, it would mean that I would need to duplicate 100 times those layers specifications.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
...
"sources": {
    "tests": [{
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "mbtiles://test1.mbtiles"
    },
    {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "mbtiles://test2.mbtiles"
    }]

...
```

or

```
...
"sources": {
    "tests": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": ["mbtiles://test1.mbtiles", "mbtiles://test2.mbtiles"]
    }

...
```

Obviously both solutions above don't work.
Thanks in advance for your feedbacks!

Comment: do you have found any solutions for this problem?

Comment: I've asked a similar question here https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl/issues/368#issuecomment-1613831871 but it doesn't look like there's any solution with tileserver-gl at the moment...